# Get Product Options From Big Commerce

Tags: bigcommerce

I need a little help. I am working with big commerce API and I am stuck at a point. Here is something that I want to achieve. I have retrieved the order details and then the products from it. Now I want to somehow get the options that are attached to the specific product.

This is what my code looks like...

```
$minutes_to_go_back = 165;                              
$time = time() - ($minutes_to_go_back * 60);//calculating time
$date =  date(DateTime::RFC2822,$time);//getting date in required format
$filter = array('min_date_created' => $date);//query filter
$orders = Bigcommerce::getOrders($filter);//received all the orders in last '$minutes_to_go_back' minutes
$order_products = $orders[$i]->products();//getting products of orders..one by one traversing through orders
print_r($order_products);
```

This is what it prints.

[image]

You will see there is an option that says Gift Message. I want to get its value. Can someone please guide me on how to do that?

Thanks in Advance for any help.
Ahmad

Comment: I've also run into this, there is an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php/issues/45) that may be getting resolved.

Comment: I managed to solve the issue myself mate...

Comment: How were you able to resolve this? I have already contact their API team requesting an update and/or fix.

Comment: let me know what you are tying to achieve. May be i help you out. :)

Comment: Thanks for the offer of assistance, it is appreciated :-) Though I was finally able to resolve this with the BigCommerce API team, and have posted a working code sample below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working for a couple days with the BigCommerce team, I was finally able to get this issue resolved for my own use, so I thought the solution would be useful here for fellow Google travellers:

```
include_once './vendor/autoload.php';
use Bigcommerce\Api\Client as Bigcommerce;

Bigcommerce::configure(array(
    'store_url' => 'YOUR_URL',
    'username'  => 'YOUR_USERNAME',
    'api_key'   => 'YOUR_API_KEY'
));
Bigcommerce::setCipher('RC4-SHA');
Bigcommerce::verifyPeer(false);


$ping = Bigcommerce::getTime();
if ($ping) echo $ping->format('H:i:s'); 

$orderID = "78165";

$options = Bigcommerce::getCollection('/orders/' . $orderID . '/products/', 'OrderProduct');
print_r($options);
```